# mpd: no audio output with PulseAudio, no mixing with ALSA

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio, mpd

I am trying to use mpd with PulseAudio output. Thus I wrote the following in `/etc/mpd.conf`:

```
music_directory "/mnt/dados/Musicas"
playlist_directory "~/.mpd/playlists"
db_file "~/.mpd/mpd.db"
log_file "~/.mpd/mpd.log"
pid_file "~/.mpd/mpd.pid"
state_file "~/.mpd/mpdstate"
user "renan"

audio_output {
   type         "pulse"
   name         "MPD Output"
}

mixer_type         "software"
```

mpd is running as user `renan`. However, I get no output; appears this in mpd.log:

```
Feb 15 20:24 : output: Failed to enable "MPD Output" [pulse]: pa_context_connect() has failed: Connection refused
Feb 15 20:24 : output: Failed to enable "MPD Output" [pulse]: pa_context_connect() has failed: Connection refused
Feb 15 20:24 : output: Failed to enable "MPD Output" [pulse]: pa_context_connect() has failed: Connection refused
Feb 15 20:24 : output: Failed to enable "MPD Output" [pulse]: pa_context_connect() has failed: Connection refused
Feb 15 20:24 : output: Failed to enable "MPD Output" [pulse]: pa_context_connect() has failed: Connection refused
Feb 15 20:24 : output: Failed to enable "MPD Output" [pulse]: pa_context_connect() has failed: Connection refused
```

If I try to use ALSA by adding the lines below to `/etc/mpd.conf`, `mpd` works but it blocks the audio device: if I open any other software that plays sound it will be unable to play sound, and vice-versa.

```
audio_output {
   type         "alsa"
   name         "My ALSA Device"
   device         "hw:0,0"  
   format         "44100:16:2"   
}
```

The rest of my system has no problem outputting audio through PulseAudio. What am I doing wrong?

I run x64 Arch Linux and have the following MPD/PulseAudio related packages installed:

```
lib32-libpulse 3.0-1
libmpd 11.8.17-1
libmpdclient 2.7-1
libpulse 3.0-2
mpd 0.17.3-1
mpdscribble 0.22-6
pulseaudio 3.0-2
pulseaudio-alsa 2-2
python2-mpd 0.3.0-4
```

Comment: According to the [mpd wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mpd), your `.conf` for Pulse should read: `audio_output {
        type                    "pulse"
        name                    "pulse audio"
}`

Comment: I tried this; did not work.

Comment: I've got the same problem on Arch. Unfortunately I just drop mpd.

Comment: Found something here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=155456

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently [it is a known problem since the migration to systemd](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=155456). Worked around by editing the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mpd.service` file and adding the lines

```
[Service]
User=renan
PAMName=system-local-login
```

(replace `renan` by your username)

Then, if it works, it should appear in the PulseAudio mixer with the name you gave in the configuration file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

User "renan" must be a member of group "audio". Do

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G audio renan
```

Comment: I am already a member of this group.